# How do I retrieve the apiId when creating a CfnDeployment via CDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm using `aws-cdk-lib` version 2 to create a CloudFormation stack. I define my API as follows:

```
const api = new apigatewayv2.CfnApi(this, 'MyApi', { body: YAML.parse(apiSpec), failOnWarnings: true });
```

This successfully creates my API on deploy. Now I'd like to automate creating a stage for this API. This is what I'm attempting:

```
new apigatewayv2.CfnStage(this, 'dev-stage', {
  stageName: 'dev',
  apiId: '???????', // <--- How do I find this value?
  autoDeploy: true,
});
```

As you can see, one of the required parameters when creating `CfnStage` is `apiId`, which doesn't seem available via the `CfnApi` object created earlier (there is a `logicalId` property, but it's not the value `CfnStage` is expecting).

I can find the correct value on the AWS console *after* the CDK script runs, but that doesn't do me much good if I'm trying to automate the creation of the stage via CDK all in a single deploy.

So: How do I determine the correct `apiId` when creating a `CfnStage` without having to have already deployed the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Ref`.

> [AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html): Ref: When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref function, Ref returns the API ID, such as a1bcdef2gh.

```js
// synth-time token, deploy-time string
const apiId = cdk.Fn.ref(api.logicalId);
```