# Using Cloudfront with an HTTP API Origin

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-http-api

I want to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS. So I want to put my app, which runs on an API Gateway, behind Cloudfront. But I want to use `aws_cdk.aws_cloudfront` to launch my Cloudfront instance.

```py
self.distribution = cloudfront.Distribution(
    self,
    construct_id,
    default_behaviour=cloudfront.BehaviorOptions(
        origin=cloudfront_origins.RestApiOrigin(api),
        ...
```

This would be my ideal implementation. But my `api` is of type `HttpApi`; I am using `aws_apigatewayv2_alpha`.

**Is there any way I can use an `HttpApi` as the origin of my Cloudfront distribution, using `aws_cloudfront`?**

Answer (score 1):

You can create Origins from any HTTP endpoint like below, given the domain name, and optionally, other origin properties.

```
# Creates a distribution from an HTTP endpoint
cloudfront.Distribution(self, "myDist",
    default_behavior=cloudfront.BehaviorOptions(origin=origins.HttpOrigin("www.example.com"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm currently following that method, but I don't want to hardcode my URL. I'm creating the API using the cdk, so I have an `api_stack.py` that runs `apigw.HttpApi(...)`, and I'm then taking that instance's property `url` and trying to pass it into `HttpOrigin`. The problem is that the `url` value looks like this `${Token[TOKEN.622]}.execute-api.eu-west-2.${Token[AWS.URLSuffix.8]}/` (`https://` prefix manually removed).

Comment: I presume these `Token`s are a way of waiting for AWS to resolve values, though they're new to me.

Comment: It also seems it would be very possible [using the console](https://skildops.com/blog/exposing-http-api-gateway-via-aws-cloudfront-detailed-guide), though I want to keep it all in code.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-solutions-constructs/blob/111dcbe9bec65f66ed6fbde5b519141af6e0d290/source/patterns/%40aws-solutions-constructs/core/lib/cloudfront-distribution-defaults.ts) of a dynamically passed url (though they're using RestApi). I presume they don't have Token issues.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your concerns can you please explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: Sure. I don't want to paste the invoke url of my Http Api into `HttpOrigin(...)` because I want the value to be dynamically linked to the creation of my api, which occurs in the same deployment. But the value of my api's url is currently littered with [Tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html). At the moment I am trying `cdk.Token.as_string(api.url.replace("https://", ""))` to overcome these issues. But I was really hoping there would have been a method `origins.HttpApi(...)`!

Comment: Yes, `cdk.Token.as_string(api.url.replace("https://", ""))` still failed with `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution: The parameter origin name must be a domain name.` Maybe creating a Cloudfront distribution with HttpOrigin is a method which isn't prepared for Tokens (though I know too little to believe that is the case or that it shouldn't be the case).

Comment: Okay, I understand the `api.url` is tokenized so URL passing to HttpOrigin won't work. I think in this case, you need to build the domain name from several other properties :-`${restApiId}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}`

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately, `restApiId` is generated by AWS and I don't have its value anywhere until its Token resolves. For now I will just use a hardcoded URL until finding a better solution.

Comment: In fact I can see your solution in use [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/dicomweb-wado-qido-stow-serverless/blob/3391ba690e872b900eec78c92de7395f8c0dfbeb/cdk/cdk/infrastructure.py#L83) (lines 66 and 83), but again using a rest api. I will check whether this is possible with an http api.

Comment: Unfortunately using `api.api_id` and `api.http_api_id` (both documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_alpha/HttpApi.html)) return Tokens.

Comment: This answer might help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70753147/12326605